# Why doesnt my react if statement work with "or"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get a console.log when my newPlan does not equal one of the selected options but it only works without the or statement "||"

Where am I going wrong?

```
      if(newPlan !== "monthlyPlan" || "yearlyPlan"){
    console.log("test2")
    this.setState({
      errorState: "error"
  });
  }
```

Comment: You have to do `if(newPlan !== "monthlyPlan" && newPlan !== "yearlyPlan"){`

Comment: Thanks @Dave. That worked but I don't understand why an and statement works in that case? Do you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain, you need to program in "computer talk" and not in english.  Yes, you would say in english "if it's not monthlyPlan or yearlyPlan", but you need to say "if it's not monthlyPlan and it's not yearlyPlan".   It's just the way it is in programming.  The way you have it now is equivalent to `if newPlan is not "monthlyPlan" || !!"yearlyPlan" === true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(newPlan !== "monthlyPlan" && newPlan !== "yearlyPlan"){
    console.log("test2")
    this.setState({
      errorState: "error"
  });
  }
```

**EDIT - Explanation:**

The && operator only becomes true if all conditions are true. In your case: if newPlan !== "monthlyPlan" is true and newPlan !== "yearlyPlan" is false the whole block becomes false.

Comment: Alternatively, if there are more than 2, it might be better to build a `Set` of all values and do a membership test

Comment: @JordanKowal there are more than two. 4 to be exact I just cut down the code for this example. What would be the best practice for this?

Comment: If they never change, you could make a `const excludedPlans = new Set(["monthlyPlan", "yearlyPlan", "..."]);` and then, your condition would simply be _newPlan not in the set_ which is written: `!excludedPlans.has(newPlan)`. This would also work with an `Array` rather than a `Set` (and you'd use `Array.includes(value)`) but sets are usually better for membership tests (membership test means: is X in Y?)

Comment: Maybe you should try another approach and put the error at the end (since you will do something with all the other conditions anyways: `if (newPlan === "monthlyPlan") {**do something**} else if (newPlan === "yearlyPlan") {**do something else**} else if (other condition) {**do more**} else {this.setState({
      errorState: "error"
  })}`

Answer (score 0):

```
   Just give condition in both cases,
```

```js
 if(newPlan !== "monthlyPlan" ||newPlan !=="yearlyPlan"){
    console.log("test2")
    this.setState({
      errorState: "error"
  });
  }
```

Comment: can you give an example of a value of `newPlan` where that if condition would be false?

Comment: in this it will give always true

Comment: you have to put && instead of ||